# Responding to Exposé in MacOS

Tags: macos

Is it possible to for an app to respond to Expose on MacOS such that it can choose what gets displayed?

I often use Expose to switch windows. The problem is if the windows look similar then it's harder to know at a glance which one I want.

[image: expose thumbnails]

Trying to switch to one of the 4 Visual Studio Code windows or one of the 4 terminal windows is not as easy as it could be if each window showed more info, for example the document name.

I can hover the mouse over each window but that's not "at a glance" so what I'd like to do is, if and only if Expose appears, choose what Expose shows for my app.

One solution I thought of is to change the display if my app's window does not have the focus. Unfortunately that's not a solution. Often I have windows side by side so I can see both windows. If I changed the display of the unfocused window that would make side by side unusable.

Does MacOS provide an API for responding to expose? Note: I'm asking a programming question. If I was to want to add this feature to Visual Studio Code or ITerm2 or my own app what is the MacOS level event I trigger on? I've never seen an app change its representation in expose so I'm guessing there is no way to do it.

Comment: Did you try the `miniWindowImage` property on your windows? [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419185-miniwindowimage?language=objc)